# Get collection or array of uploaded files

Tags: laravel, collections, multipartform-data

I have an issue with a form data. I have many files in an array but when I have to get them in my controller I use `file()` but it doesn't returns a collection of uploaded files, so I'm looking for a solution to make it possible. My client is Anguler and my API is Laravel.

So when I send my request I get my files :

```
 (2) [File, File]
```

But I don't know how to create a collection so I'm stuck with this piece of code that gives me only one file. when I `dd()` I get only one file.

```
 $files= $req->file('files');
```

I would like to make this :

```
$files->each(function ($item, $key) {
    //some code...
});
```

**EDIT**
I change the logic in the client side to create many files with different key names in order to loop after getting the request content.

```
for (var i = 0; i < email.file.length; i++) {
      form.append('file'+[i], email.file[i], email.file[i].name);
    }
```

Now i have :

```
#parameters: array:2 [▼
    "file0" => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile {#33 ▶}
    "file1" => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile {#34 ▶}
  ]
```

So I get an object and I would like to convert it to an array or a collection.

Comment: you can access the files by $request->files and then you can use foreach to access each file

Comment: It seems that $req->files is not a collection or an array.

Comment: can you show related client side code?

Comment: at client side i did like this:
`
          for (let key in imagedata.files) {
            formData.append("images[]", imagedata.files[key]);
          }
`
now i can access images as array by $request->images in controller, you can use `col()` method if you want turn array to collection

Comment: I get an array of array in the dd() but gettype() returns an object.

Comment: change:
 
      `form.append('file'+[i], email.file[i], email.file[i].name);`
to

      `form.append('file[]', email.file[i]);`

on your client side

Comment: I did add this to the code but it's still an object.

Comment: very weird! please paste dd($req->files) output here.

Comment: from your browser inspect -> network -> request tab. can you see all image data there? it should be multiple image with same key

Comment: I only have this : file[]: (binary)
file[]: (binary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced this :

```
$files= $req->file('files');
```

to :

```
$req->files->all();
```

thanks to [this doc](http://l3.shihan.me/api/class-Symfony.Component.HttpFoundation.ParameterBag.html#_get)